# Using Amnesia with Distillery

Tags: elixir, mnesia, distillery

Is it possible to use Amnesia with distillery.  Because mix is unavailable in a distillery release, I am unsure how I would go about creating the mnesia db.

Answer (score 1):

The [distillery docs](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/running-migrations.html#content) provide some guidance on running tasks like migrations.

The [Amnesia mix task](https://github.com/meh/amnesia/blob/master/lib/mix/amnesia.create.ex#L19) seems to simply call into your database modules `create!` function:

```
  def run(args) do
    options = parse_args(args)
    copying = parse_copying(options)
    db = ensure_database_module(options[:database])

    if options[:schema] do
      Amnesia.Schema.create
    end

    Amnesia.start
    try do
      db.create!(copying)
      :ok = db.wait(15000)
    after
      Amnesia.stop
    end
  end
```

So you should be able to replicate this in your own module, and invoke it with a distillery [custom command](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/running-migrations.html#custom-command)